# Creating ahk sleep timers quick edit

Tags: autohotkey

So I'm making a rather long auto clicker and I was wondering if since most of my sleep timers will be the same of there is anyway to just have a %var% or something at the beginning of the script to change them all at the same time instead of going individually to each

Comment: Yes, you can define e.g. `var := 300` on the top of your script and replace the following sleep commands with `Sleep %var%`.

Comment: Sweet thank you! Can I do var 1:= 300 var2 :=600 ?

Comment: There is no limit to how many variables a script may contain. Variable names with spaces (`var 1` in your example) are not allowed.

Comment: So it needs to be var1 := 300 and var2 := 600 right? And one last question if its possible I would like to keep looping the same set of code over and over but after each loop it clicks a different set of coords is it possible to have it loop but each time it hits the } bracket it goes to a different coord than repeats the bracket code?

Comment: You can use `A_Index` within the [loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm): If (A_Index = 1) -> do this, If (A_Index = 2) -> do that etc.

Comment: So if my code was told to { Loop, 40 { Click L, 111, 222 Sleep, %var1% } Click L, 222, 333 Sleep, %var2% } how would I write it to make  it click the second coord than go back to the loop?

Comment: Also sorry I dont know how to write that properly in the comments

Comment: Please, edit your question with the new information or ask a new one because it's a different question as the original asked. You can refer to this question in your new question.